# Авторизация и парсинг страницы

Tags: golang

Я использую **goquery** библиотеку, она для меня самая легкая и надежная, но вот только она сама отправлять запрос в объекте `goquery.NewDocument` и там нельзя выставлять параметры для POST запроса чтоб авторизироваться, как быть?

Comment: Я для контроля параметров запроса использую связку httpclient + goquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со слов разработки данной библиотеке это сделать нельзя и в дальнейшем не планируется. Он рекомендует использовать другую библиотеку для получение html страниц, а потом использовать его библиотеку для парсинга. 
Ссылка на похожий вопрос https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/pull/203

Надеюсь правильно нашел библиотеку, которую Вы используете.